# How can I edit the Keywords field in SharePoint using c#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I can edit other fields like Title and even my own created fields, but I cant figure out how to add in Keywords to a document I upload. This is what I have so far. The error I get says that the Keywords column does not exist. The Keywords fields type is Managed Metadata. Here is a image of where I want to add keywords into [Here is a image of where I want to add keywords into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a6oU.png)

Update: Here is the updated code of what worked

```
    static void AddMetaData(ClientContext ctx, string fName, string kWords )
    {
        List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
        ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
        ctx.Load(items); // loading all the fields
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        TaxonomySession session = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(ctx);
        var store = session.GetDefaultKeywordsTermStore();
        var terms = store.KeywordsTermSet.GetAllTerms();
        ctx.Load(store, i => i.DefaultLanguage);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        var collection = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Term>();
        var keywords = kWords.Split(';');
        foreach (var key in keywords)
        {
            var filtered = ctx.LoadQuery(terms.Where(t => t.Name == key));
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            var term = filtered.SingleOrDefault();
            if (term != null)
                collection.Add(term);
        }

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var taxonomyField = ctx.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Keywords"));
            ctx.Load(taxonomyField);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            taxonomyField.SetFieldValueByCollection(item, collection, store.DefaultLanguage);
            item.Update();
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a taxonomy field so first you have to get your keywords from the managed metadata store:

```
TaxonomySession session = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(context);
var store = session.GetDefaultKeywordsTermStore();
var terms = store.KeywordsTermSet.GetAllTerms();
context.Load(store, i => i.DefaultLanguage);
context.ExecuteQuery();

var collection = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Term>();
var keywords = new string[] { "Key1", "Key2" };
foreach (var key in keywords)
{
    var filtered = context.LoadQuery(terms.Where(t => t.Name == key));
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    var term = filtered.SingleOrDefault();
    if (term != null)
        collection.Add(term);
}
```

Then set field using method contained in TaxonomyField class:

```
var taxonomyField = context.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Keywords"));
context.Load(taxonomyField);
context.ExecuteQuery();
taxonomyField.SetFieldValueByCollection(item, collection, store.DefaultLanguage);
item.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Ok when I tried it out I got "The 'Contains' member cannot be used in the expression." for this line
var filtered = context.LoadQuery(terms.Where(t => keywords.Contains(t.Name)));

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have been having trouble with this for 2 days. I am not sure if I am using the code correctly I am getting a problem with store.DefaultLanguage

Comment: Happy to help. If everything works please vote up and mark as answered :)

Comment: It says The property or field 'DefaultLanguage' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Comment: this is where I get the default language problem

foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    var taxonomyField = context.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("Keywords"));
                    context.Load(taxonomyField);
                    context.ExecuteQuery();
                    taxonomyField.SetFieldValueByCollection(item, collection, store.DefaultLanguage);
                }

Comment: add before your code: context.Load(store, i => i.DefaultLanguage);
context.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: ok so it looks like I am not getting errors but where do the new keywords actually get added in? my file on SharePoint is still empty on keywords

Comment: try adding context.ExecuteQuery(); after taxonomyField.SetFieldValueByCollection

Comment: ok I added in the line but still no luck. With this code what should be added in to the keywords field? Is it the values in  var keywords = new string[] { "Keyword 1", "Keyword 2" };

Comment: I added in a picture into the original post so you can see where I am trying to add the keywords into. so far the Keywords column is still empty.

Comment: I figured it out I was missing item.update(); after taxonomyField.SetFieldValueByCollection(item, collection, store.DefaultLanguage);

Comment: touche :D I forgot - nice job :)