# SPFx how to update Enterprise Keyword Column, JSOM, CSOM, REST?

Tags: typescript, sharepoint, sharepoint-jsom, spfx

I am using SharePoint Online and try to build a SPFx WebPart. I am able to retrieve `Enterprise Keywords` stored in my InteractionLogList, with `Label` and `GUID`. As well I am able to retrieve all the Taxonomy Keywords with `Label` and `GUID`. Therefore I can show them for existing list items. I can search and select using the `TagPicker`. I am not able to store those values back to the List.

I read on [Jason Lee's Blog](http://www.jrjlee.com/2017/01/getting-or-setting-multi-value-metadata.html) to use REST API, a hidden field and to ensure no blanks in the label, or the list is corrupted. There's been a request for over a year to include Taxonomy in REST.

It seems to me JSOM would be a better way, but I couldn't find enough information to get started. I am new to the entire SPFx, TypeScript thing. I got long programming experience with C++ and C#.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44269716/1498401

Comment: Thank you. I think [JavaScript API for SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj193034.aspx) contains the functions needed, as in your link. Now I just gotta figure how I import to the JavaScript API into my SPFx project.

Comment: I got the tutorials mixed up, here is one for JSOM [dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-sharepoint-using-jsom](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-sharepoint-using-jsom)

Comment: Important to be aware of the small issue [Kept on getting error message for @types/sharepoint #668](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/668)